# Port forwarding of Windows Network File Share

Tags: port-forwarding, shared-folders

I want to access Windows Network File/Folder share inside a NAT network across the internet using NAT port forwarding, For this to succeed, which **port numbers** should I forward to the Windows 10 client from router?

Also what transport protocol do they use?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access Windows Network File/Folder share inside a NAT network across the internet using NAT port forwarding

Windows "File Sharing" uses the SMB protocol.

Historically, the Windows SMB server has had a very large number of security holes in it (and new ones are still found). Exposing it to the Internet is not recommended for that reason.

And not only that – many ISPs will actually block connections on the SMB ports, so even if you set up port-forwarding perfectly (or even if you assign the public IP address directly to the server), very likely you will not be able to access the service anyway.

> which port numbers should I forward to the Windows 10 client from router?

None. SMB connections, like most other services, are initiated *from* the client to the server.

If the SMB *server* itself is behind NAT, then you need port forwarding on its end, but not on the client's end; there are no separate reverse connections that are made to the client.

(Once an outbound connection is establishd, inbound reply packets do not need a port-forwarding rule as they're handled by connection tracking – exactly like you don't need to forward any ports to a web browser i.e. a HTTP client.)

> which port numbers [...] Also what transport protocol do they use?

SMBv3 uses TCP and runs over TCP port 445 only.

The old SMBv1 used different TCP ports, as well as some UDP ports for NetBIOS, but none of those are necessary for SMBv2 / SMBv3 in modern Windows versions.

(The transport protocol really needs to be part of the main question, and not an "also" afterthought, because each transport protocol defines its own "port number" facility – not the other way around.)